# Testing React/Redux app with componentWillMount() this.props.dispatch() call

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, enzyme

Here is a stripped down version of my Redux/React component:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import Header from "./components/Header";
import { getMoviesInit } from "./actions/movieActions";

export class Layout extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        if (this.props.movies.length == 0) {
            this.props.dispatch((dispatch) => {
                dispatch(getMoviesInit());
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="content-wrap">
            <Header/>
            {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
};

export default connect((store) => {
    return {
        movies: store.movies
    };
})(Layout);
```

When I try to run a test like the following, I'm told I this.props.dispatch() isn't a function which makes sense because there is a dispatch() call in the componentWillMount() function and I'm not using the connect() wrapped Layout:

```
import React from "react";
import LayoutWithConnect, { Layout } from "./Layout";
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { expect } from 'chai';

describe("Layout tests", function() {
    beforeEach(() => {
        let movies = {
            featuredId: null,
            currentTitles: {
                movies: []
            }
        };
        let subject = shallow(<Layout movies={movies} />);
    });
});
```

However, if I try to use LayoutWithConnect in my test I get issues with there not being a store.

I'm not sure how I should be going about testing this component?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass the `dispatch` function as a prop:

```
let dispatchedAction;
let dispatch = (action) => dispatchedAction = action;
let subject = shallow(<Layout movies={movies} dispatch={dispatch} />);
```

You can then also test that the view dispatched the correct action by comparing `dispatchedAction` with the expected action object.

If you find yourself doing this often, you can also use the excellent [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) stubbing/mocking library, which allows you to easily create [spy](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#spies) functions:

```
let dispatch = sinon.spy();
let subject = shallow(<Layout movies={movies} dispatch={dispatch} />);

expect(dispatch.calledWith(expectedAction)).to.be.true;
```